# How to find period of following trigonometric question

Tags: functions, trigonometry

You are swinging on a swing in your backyard. When sitting still you are 1.5m off the ground. Once you are swinging consistently your maximum height off the ground is 4 m. It takes 3 seconds to travel from the highest point in front of the swing to the highest point behind the swing. You are at the highest position in front of the swing at t=0.

a) Determine a cosine function that could be used to model your height off the ground over time. Show all work.

b) Determine a sine function that could be used to model your height off the ground over time. Show all work.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a physics style answer 
The time period is 3 as it takes that much time to oscillate between amplitudes or in other terms of the function is h = h0 +a*sin(2pi*t/T)
A is amplitude h0 is original height T is time period pi is 3.14159
ho is clearly 1.5 as at t=0 h0 =1.5
 a is 2.5m as maximum height is 4m
Hence the function required is h=1.5 +2.5*sin(2*pi*t/3)

Comment: Here asin is a into sin not inverse sine

Comment: Thanks. I thought the period is 3+3=6 seconds since period is represent a full cycle (time it takes a child being pushed in a swing to be pushed and then return back for another push so 3 + 3 =6).

Comment: It says: " It takes 3 seconds to travel from the highest point in front of the swing to the highest point behind the swing". What about time to travel back: from highest point behind the swing to the highest point in front of the swing??? (3 + 3 = 6)